# Selecionar apenas um RadioButton com Razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho 2 Radio Buttons, e gostaria que quando eu marcasse um, o outro desmarcasse.

Segue a imagem do que está ocorrendo:

[image]

Código:

```
@Html.RadioButton("teste", "teste", true) Teste
@Html.RadioButton("concessionaria", "concessionaria", false) Concessionária
```

Comment: Voce pode usar o attr('checked', true) true ou false no caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Coloque assim:***

```
@Html.RadioButton("teste", "teste", true)
@Html.RadioButton("teste", "concessionaria")
```

Porque os `input` `type` `radio` devem possuir o mesmo nome, sendo a sua diferença pelo `value`.

***Exemplo com form:***

```
<form action="/Estudo/Post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @Html.RadioButton("teste", "teste", true)
        @Html.RadioButton("teste", "concessionaria")
        <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

***Renderizado Html:***

```
<form action="/Estudo/Post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input checked="checked" id="teste" name="teste" type="radio" value="teste" />
        <input id="teste" name="teste" type="radio" value="concessionaria" />
        <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

*Observe que os dois possui o mesmo nome com value diferentes que podem ser recuperados pela método `Post`.*

***Recuperando pelo Método `Post`***

```
public ActionResult Post(string teste)
{
      return View();
}
```

***Debug:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]